# actionbar sherlock replace home icon with dropdown icon or remove it completely

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have tried to replace the home icon with a dropdown icon,I have also tried removing it completely but I am unable to achieve it.

[image]

the home icon in the above fig ie:

[image]
<sub>(source: [gstatic.com](https://g0.gstatic.com/android/market/com.actionbarsherlock.sample.styledactionbar/hi-256-0-66b44fcb53c53ffdb7b6b6ab23ebb5b9aecdab6a))</sub>

needs to be replaced with drop down or completely removed.How do I do it?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove the home action item by calling

`getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);`

If you want to replace it with a drop-down menu your best bet would be constructing a `Spinner` and using the action bar's custom view.

```
Spinner dropdown = new Spinner(this);
//TODO attach to an adapter of some sort
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(dropdown);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Thank you Sir.But What if I have to use dropdown with icons rather than text like this in fig: http://img37.imageshack.us/img37/1513/screenshot2012012821300.png , but instead of day,week and month I would like to have icons in the home icon position.